# Can't activate hardware acceleration using windows 10 family and amd processor

Tags: windows-10, amd-ryzen, acceleration

I would like to create a virtual device in Android Studio but I can't because hardware acceleration is disabled.

I went to the BIOS and there are two option :

```
AMD-SVM
AMD-IOMMU
```

Both are enabled.

I also downloaded the HAXM installer from the SDK manager and tried to run it from the

```
C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
```

with intelhaxm-android file.

I got an error telling me :

```
This computer does not support Intel Virtualization technology VT X or it is exclusively used by Hyper V. HAXM cannot be installed. Please ensure that hyper V is disabled in windows feature
```

It makes sense that I can't activate Intel Virtualization technology because I have AMD Ryzen 7 2700U.

With my previous computer it worked just fine but I had an Intel processor.

Some tutorials online suggested to enable windows Hyper-V feature but it's only available for windows 10 pro.

Does anyone know a way to activate hardware acceleration with AMD processor and without Hyper-V feature?

Answer (score 1):

> I got an error telling me :
>
> "This computer does not support Intel Virtualization technology VT X or it is exclusively used by Hyper V. HAXM cannot be installed. Please ensure that Hyper-V is disabled in Windows Feature"

This is due to the fact that HAXM does not support AMD-V.

> We don't plan to implement, maintain, or validate this ourselves, but
>   we don't have any objections to seeing another team of developers
>   extend HAXM to support AMD-V. However, while Intel VT and AMD-V serve
>   similar functions, they're different enough that this would be a
>   substantial undertaking, one that would have a major impact on the
>   architecture of the driver.
>
> We currently have a full-time team of developers maintaining and validating this driver, with expertise in Intel VT. We'd be willing to work with someone (preferably a team of someones) interested in seeing support for AMD-V, to work out the details for what such support should look like, how it should be maintained and validated, and whether it makes more sense to integrate or to maintain a common API across independent drivers.

Source: [AMD CPU support](https://github.com/intel/haxm/issues/5)

HAXM is an open-sourced hypervisor developed by Intel.  So it is unlikely AMD-V support will be added to HAXM.

> On Intel x86-based computers, the Android Emulator will continue to use Intel HAXM by default. Intel HAXM is a mature and open-sourced hypervisor solution developed by Intel.

[image]

> I would like to create a virtual device in Android Studio but I can't because hardware acceleration is disabled.

It actually is enabled based on the fact AMD-V is enabled.  You are getting the error due to the fact HAXM does not support AMD-V.

> Does anyone know a way to activate hardware acceleration with AMD processor and without Hyper-V feature ?

You would need an Intel processor to avoid installing Hyper-V.  In this case, due to your processor, using Hyper-V is your only solution.

[Android Emulator - AMD Processor & Hyper-V Support](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking answers to this question now, this Android Studio blog post from October 2019 helped me solve this problem: [Android Studio Release Updates: Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors - Canary SDK Package, Install Instructions](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/10/android-emulator-hypervisor-driver-for.html)

Basically there is a separate hypervisor for AMD processor owners that you can use instead of HAMX. Steps are the following:

- Make sure your AMD CPU supports virtualization, and that virtualization has been enabled from BIOS.
- Anything related to Hyper-V should be disabled from "Windows Features", basically the following: Hyper-V, Windows Hypervisor Platform, Windows Sandbox.
- Open SDK Manager from Android Studio, and install "Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors".
- Open a Windows command console with administrator privileges.
- Go to `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT\extras\google\Android_Emulator_Hypervisor_Driver`. By default `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` points to `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`.
- Run `silent_install.bat`. Output from the installer should show: `STATE: 4 RUNNING`.

And that should be it, after this creating the Virtual Device should no longer complain about HAMX missing.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, edited the answer now to do just that.