# Running Android Studio emulator on Ryzen?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am running into issues with running android studio on Ryzen. I have done the following steps:

1. Enabled Hyper-V in Windows through "Enable Windows Features"
2. I am on Version 3.3 of Android Studio.
3. I have enabled SVM in my BIOS.

The error:

`Your CPU does not support required features (VT-x or SVM)`

I am not sure what else I can do, is there still no support for AMD Ryzen cpus?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Can't activate hardware acceleration using windows 10 family and amd processor](https://superuser.com/questions/1401671/cant-activate-hardware-acceleration-using-windows-10-family-and-amd-processor/1401827#1401827)

Comment: Android Studio does not support AMD-V.

Comment: It does not appear you have the Windows Hypervisor Platform installed.  Sadly, due to the fact, the duplicate's answer was never accepted or upvoted I can't actually flag this as a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Android Studio 3.4.
To get it working you need to disable Hyper-V and enable the Windows Hypervisor Platform.

[image]